# Solr query require specifically "fieldname:searchtext" for custom data

Tags: xml, solr

Regarding the Solrj interface, why is it that for the default xml example (E.g. hd.xml), I can easily query it by just typing "**samsung**" in the query textbox. But for my own custom xml data, I need to type "**fieldname:whatever**". No result of my data will be shown if I don't specifically add a fieldname in front.

I made use of the dynamicfield

```
<dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

so I added a "_t" in every one of my custom fields.

```
<field name="id">3</field>
<field name="full_message_t">[CNA] Grace Fu meets China’s NPC vice chairperson http://t.co/6k9CLe4c1x</field>
<field name="source_t">CNA</field>
<field name="news_t">Grace Fu meets China’s NPC vice chairperson </field>
<field name="link_t">http://t.co/6k9CLe4c1x</field>
```

So for example:
 if I just type "**CNA**" in the query textbox, nothing shows up. If I type "**source_t:CNA**", then my expected results shows up. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

There is something like a copy Fields in solr. Copy fields can copy your indexes to a common field. So then if you query on that field all the data will be searched.

```
<field name="id">3</field>
<field name="source_t">CNA</field>
```

You should define copy fields as

```
<copyField source="id" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="source_t" dest="text"/>
```

Here dest stands for the destination field... check what is the default query field for your solr distribution and use it in the destination.

Please check your defaultsearchfield tag in schema.xml it should be

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

for this particular case.

Then you can search it without specifying a particular field.

Comment: Hi javacreed. You are referring to changes made in schema.xml only? By the way, do you mean <copyField source="source_t" dest="text"/> or <copy field="source_t" dest="text"/>? Because I tried both and neither works. Was there something else I needed to change/add?

Comment: copyField it should be...But can you check your schema file to see what is the defaultsearchfield of your schema.It should be <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

Comment: I am getting error for <copyField="source_t" dest="text"/>. Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: solrres:/schema.xml; lineNum
ber: 285; columnNumber: 12; Element type "copyField" must be followed by either
attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: Add name attr to the field

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I finally figured the problem, here is the step by step solution:

Add in the fields to schema.xml

```
<copyField source="full_message_t" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="source_t" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="news_t" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="link_t" dest="text"/>
```

Uncomment this:

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

Restart Solr.

```
java -jar start.jar
```

And finally (this is the step that I missed), re-import your custom xml data.

```
java -jar post.jar [name].xml
```

Comment: Restart the solr!!! Obviously you would do that and you create a new answer for this.